# How to reorganise files location without updating each node manually?

Tags: 8

In my file system, I have different folders where are stored the files linked to the nodes (either pictures in the body of the node or pictures in a 'Gallery' field I added to custom content type).

I'd like to reorganize all these folders in a more structured way.
How can I do that without editing each of these nodes?

Is there a way to update the database, e.g. change `mydomainname/sites/default/files/mypicture.png` (or whatever) to `mydomainname/sites/default/files/pictures/yyyymmdd/mypicture.png` where yyyymmdd is related to an event, for example?

My version of Drupal is 8.5.6.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you'd move the files and mass update via SQL the file paths, but its probably more complicated in Drupal 8. Also, you have a dynamic value in your new path (event date) which would make this impossible if not extremely tedious to script out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to fo this, I have the same situation in my previous project and I have achieved this by using below code:

```
    $field_name = 'FIELD_MACHINE_NAME';
    $entity_type = 'ENTITY_TYPE'; // Node or user
    $bundle = 'BUNDLE'; // Content Type.
    $table_field = $field_name . '_target_id';
    $table = $entity_type . '__' . $field_name;
    $db_conn = \Drupal::database();
    $query = $db_conn->select($table, 'th');
    $query->leftJoin('file_managed', 'fm', 'fm.fid = th.' . $table_field);
    $query->fields('th', ['entity_id', $table_field]);
    $query->fields('fm', ['filename']);
    $query->condition('bundle', $bundle);
    $entity_results = $query->execute()->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($entity_results as $result) {
      $fid = $result[$table_field];
      $file_load = File::load($fid);
      if ($file_load) {
        $new_directory = 'NEW DIRECTORY PATH';
        $new_uri = "public://" . $new_directory . "/" . $file_load->getFilename();
        $db_conn->update('file_managed')
          ->fields([
            'uri' => $new_uri,
          ])
          ->condition('filename', $file_load->getFilename())
          ->condition('fid', $fid)
          ->execute();
        drupal_set_message('File path changes successfully for for node id ' . $result['entity_id']);
      }
      else {
        drupal_set_message('Unable to load file for node id ' . $result['entity_id'], 'warning');
      }
    }
```

Here you have to be very careful while moving this to production. Backup DB and files before running this code.

And `drush cr` or `clear cache` after running this code for every field.